# When to create index and update document in Zend Lucene?

Tags: php, zend-search-lucene

I fiddling around with Zend Lucene and I have a question on it. When do you create an index and update document in Zend Lucene?

Do you create an index whenever you add a new record / row and update the document whenever you update an existing record / row?

Thanks.